# Does Cypress support interaction with DB2 databases?

Tags: automation, db2, cypress

I need to automate SQL injection into DB2 Database table. This is a part of E2E test I'm trying to automate using Cypress. I wonder if it is possible at all? Are there any Cypress plugins I can use?

Answer (score 0):

I could find only one cypress `plugin` for database communication. Don't know if this is the one that you are looking for.

```
https://github.com/prescottprue/cypress-firebase
```

Also please refer this `url` for more database interaction.

```
https://medium.com/@prescottprue/testing-react-firebase-apps-with-cypress-7d7a64d155de
```